# console.log is not removed

Tags: webpack, babeljs, uglifyjs

I am trying to remove console.log using UglifyJsPlugin when building for production. However, console.log code is not removed after building in production mode. Here is my webpack code for removing console.log.

Webpack config:

```
config.plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env': {
    NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
  }
})); // for React
config.plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin());
config.plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
  minimize: true,
  comments: false,
  compress: {
    drop_console: true
  }
})); // minimize
config.plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin()); // remove duplication
config.output.filename = "[name].[chunkhash].js";
config.output.chunkFilename = "[id].[chunkhash].bundle.js";
```

webpack module:

```
module: {
  loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: "css-loader"
  },
  {
    test: /\.less$/,
    loader: "css-loader!less-loader?{'paths': [\""+__dirname+"/src\", \""+__dirname+"/node_modules\"]}"
  },
  {
    test: /\.png|\.gif|\.jpg|\.svg|\.eot|\.woff|\.woff2|\.ttf/, loader: "file-loader"
  },
  {
    test: /\.json/,
    loader: "json-loader"
  },
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|plugins)/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
  }]
}
```

I am also using babeljs and heard that it could be the cause of this since babeljs transforms the code. Does anyone know how to handle this?

Comment: Can you share you whole config ?

Comment: @PrakashKandel updated more config

Comment: This looks good for me. Try to debug your config by `console.log` and see if it contains all the option that you expected. Have a look at this code, this works for me https://github.com/Pkandel/javascript-workshop/blob/master/webpack.config.babel.js